# Change keymap for Tree View:Toggle in Atom?

Tags: keymapping, atom-editor

I'm getting started with customizing the Atom Editor and have gotten stumped attempting to change the key mapping for Tree View:Toggle.

I put this in my user keycap.cson file:

`'.editor':
     'ctrl-t': 'Tree View:Toggle'`

But it doesn't work.

Looking at Preferences->Keybindings I see it listed as I'd expect:

`ctrl-t   Tree View:Toggle    User    .editor`

What did I do wrong?

Update:

Changing to:

`'.editor':
  'ctrl-t': 'tree-view:toggle'`

didn't fix the problem.

The Key Binding Resolver shows that the command was recognized, but it didn't toggle the tree view. See this screenshot:

http://cl.ly/image/3A2X1p350v2Q

Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: OK this started working. I don't know why. Maybe the editor had to be restarted?

Comment: When in doubt, you can always press `ctrl-alt-cmd-l` to reload the editor, but when it comes to keybindings, they should update automatically when changes are made to your `keymap.cson` file.

Comment: I think this has now been fixed in atom. It works fine in 2017 under ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

I went through the same problem! It was a pain in the ass because i needed to use my own shortcuts but atom's keybinding are different from my latin-qwerty-keyboard, so while playing around with atom and looking for some good information, i came out with this solution:

Problem:

When i type in my windows **Ctrl-Alt-\** Atom's keybinding is **Ctrl-Alt-]**

Or if i want *'@'* i need to type **Ctrl-Alt-q** but Atom's keybinding does this *'autoflow:reflow-selection'* instead.

Solution:

1._ Go to *Settings->Keybindings*. Once you're there, in the search bar, find the keybinding you want to change. For example if i want to change **Ctrl-Alt-q**, so i type: **Q** and it'll filter all keybindings with this letter.

2._Then to modify it, click int the copy&paste small-icon next to the keybinding you want to modify, it is at **Keystroke** column. (it will copy the code lines that you need so that you can modify it)

3._ Once you copied the keybinding, go to *File->Open Your Keymap* and it'll open a tab with the keymap.cson file. Put your cursor at the end and paste there the lines you copied in step#2. It should show something like this:

```
'.platform-win32 .editor, .platform-linux .editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'autoflow:reflow-selection'
```

4._ Now you can change atom's behavior. I'll erase *'autoflow:reflow-selection'* and write *'unset!'* so that it shows the arroba.

```
'.platform-win32 .editor, .platform-linux .editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'unset!'
```

Now when i type **Ctrl-Alt-q** in atom editor it shows the arroba, finally! If you want it to do something else, instead of writting *'unset!'* you just need to put whatever you want it to do.

Note: If you want to know the atom's keybindings so that you can change some of them, use the keybinding resolver, go to *Packages->Keybinding Resolver->Toggle*.

Here i post the changes i did in my keymap.cson in order to use my atom editor with my latin-qwerty-keyboard.

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  "ctrl-alt-[": "unset!",
  "ctrl-alt-]": "unset!",
  'ctrl-/': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-7': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
  'ctrl-alt-8': 'tree-view:recursive-collapse-directory'
  'ctrl-alt-8': 'editor:fold-current-row'
  'ctrl-alt-9': 'editor:unfold-current-row'
'.platform-win32 .editor, .platform-linux .editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'unset!'
'.platform-win32 .find-and-replace, .platform-linux .find-and-replace':
  'ctrl-alt-/': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-alt-7': 'find-and-replace:toggle-regex-option'
'.platform-win32 .project-find, .platform-linux .project-find':
  'ctrl-alt-/': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-alt-7': 'project-find:toggle-regex-option'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

This is easy enough to fix. You haven't correctly formatted the name of the command. It should look like the following:

```
'.editor':
  'ctrl-t': 'tree-view:toggle'
```

In the future, if things aren't working as expected, try checking out existing open source packages that you know are working and see if you can find a mismatch. For instance, you can go to the [tree-view's keymap file](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/blob/master/keymaps/tree-view.cson), `tree-view.cson`, to see how they have formatted it.

---

**Further Improvements**

You might notice that because the keybinding you have defined is tied to the *editor*, if you have the *Tree View* in focus, your keybinding won't be triggered. Again, looking at the file above, you will see a way to improve this. Tie the keybinding to the platform, `.platform-darwin` (or whichever is appropriate for you), so that it is triggered no matter which element of the editor is in focus.

```
'.platform-darwin':
  'ctrl-t': 'tree-view:toggle'
```

This, of course, raises a different issue. Now, when the editor is in focus, the existing keybinding for `editor:transpose` will take precedence because of its more specific CSS class (namely, `.editor`). Thus, the *Tree View* will not be toggled now when the *editor* is in focus. The easiest way to fix this is add the keybinding for the editor as well:

```
'.platform-darwin':
  'ctrl-t': 'tree-view:toggle'

'.editor':
  'ctrl-t': 'tree-view:toggle'
```

Now it won't matter whether the *editor* or the *Tree View* is in focus, the toggle will be triggered nonetheless.

---

**Final Thoughts**

Another bit of advice when messing around with keybindings is to utilize the *Keybinding Resolver*. You can open this with `cmd-.`. If you do this and try pressing `ctrl-t` you will notice the keybinding that you have added shows up (highlighted in green). You will also notice that your keybinding is inhibiting another keybinding, `editor:transpose`. Consider using a different keybinding.

The beauty of Atom is its customizability, just make sure you know the tradeoffs of your customizations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. But I'll be darned if that doesn't work. I've expand my original question with more information.

Comment: Are you sure the editor was in focus when you pressed the keybinding? Try changing `.editor` to one of the more general platform scopes (e.g. `.platform-darwin`.

Comment: @BobRockefeller you need to restart atom sometimes, for custom changes to take effect (still relevant on 2014-05-20)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same problem with ATOM, i almost give up!.
i have ATOM workink on a windows 8 PC.

1. If you modify your keymap.cson, RESTART the editor.
2. If you change the value of any Key Binding, create a new Key Binding for the function you changed. e.g.

I had problems with the @ and i fix it using this line

Using the Packages>KeyBinding resolver utility i get:

ctrl-alt-q was my key sequence for my @

Using the KeyBinding utility i get:
ctrl-alt-q execute autoflow:reflow-selection command

'.platform-win32 atom-text-editor, .platform-linux atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'unset!',
  'ctrl-alt-7': 'autoflow:reflow-selection'

first i unset my keybinding and then i invented a new one for the command i want to overwrite.

hope it does work for u

Comment: **restart** is the key.